# CORS with dynamic origin

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am using CORS to allow cross origin requests from my Asp.Net web Api service. When I am using -

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

I am getting medium severity error in burp report. I have dynmics origins such that -

> https://*.abc.com

. How can I allow dynamic origins in that case instead of using "*".

Answer (score 0):

I already config my apache2 with this type of `CORS` with regular expression ,I hope it will help to solve your problem.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "((http(s?))?://(www\.)?(mydomain)\.com)(:\d+)?", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: Does this really work? I don't see whether this is possible in the documentation.